Broken suspend on Thinkpad X230 OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5
I have a frustrating problem: suspend & sleep are broken on my Thinkpad X230 running Ubuntu 22.04.5
This means that when it would usually suspend, either automatically or manually, instead the screen merely goes blank and the power button pulses green, but the fan is still running. No input on keyboard etc is possible. The only way to resolve it is by long power button press to turn off and on again. I've had to turn the power settings to 'don't suspend' and only use it plugged in, for now.
I've tried the solutions on the other similar threads about this problem elsewhere on the forum, without success. Any help with this issue would be gratefully received :)
Info:
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64
Thinkpad X230
Kernel: 5.15.0-125-lowlatency [the problem persists with other kernels]
Memory: 15.3 GiB
GPU: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Gr
CPU: Intel i7-3520M (4) @ 3.600GHz
DE: Unity 7.5.1
WM: Compiz

The problem persists.
